# Searching for a digits inside numeric ranges provided in string format (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Here is the `Accomodation` table provided me by 3rd party API

```
ID              NAME   
1               1 ADL + 1 CHD (0-2) + 1 CHD (6-9) + 1 CHD (10-18)   
2               1 ADL + 1 CHD   
3               1 ADL
```

In this table, `ADL` stands for adult, `chd` stands for child. And numeric ranges inside `()` are meaning - age range of children.

So, for example if I need to find row which consists of string that means:

```
1 - Adult, 
1 - 3 years old child
1 - 5 years old child
```

it'd look like (for example)

```
1 ADL + CHD (2-5) + CHD (4 - 9)
```

So I need to look, if the ages that I'm looking for is in between these age-ranges, also analyze these strings to find right match.

Considering facts that, there might be typos in these names and this procedure needs to be done very rapidly, I'm very confused about the sql query that might help me finding right accommodation id from table.

Any suggestions? if it's not right way, what would be the right one?

Comment: You should parse this into a sensible format for querying.

Comment: If at all possible, you should look into normalizing the data. Even if you just use a stored proc to parse this into a temp table and then query that temp table, you'll probably do a lot better.

Comment: @RToyota I can't figure out the right table structure for this data. what would you suggest?

Comment: @MartinSmith please take a look at my comment above

Comment: You probably need individual columns to represent the various significant values, like `adult, child25, child49` and so on. Store it in this simple format, then render it out as whatever you want when displaying it.

Comment: @tadman personally I can't imagine column count out of this data. it would look very messy

Comment: Your data's very messy. Do you have the exact ages of the children involved? If so you could create a separate table itemizing the people involved in a simple one-to-many relationship. If not and there's a reasonable number of ranges this structure is just representative of the quirky format your data's in.

Comment: @tadman it's not my data. it's data provided by 3rd party API

Comment: @tadman I'm trying to structurize that data

Comment: I'd try the cave-man approach and have lots of columns as a baseline. A one-to-many is probably better, so I'd encourage that if you're feeling more ambitious. In that table you can have a `person_count` column and `person_type` for their category.

Comment: @tadman so what you want to tell me is, to create many to many relationship and provide every age, create connections between children and age. And then assign them into accomodation names, right? if not can you please explain me

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure this data better, so one approach is to just spell it out as a series of columns:

```
CREATE TABLE accommodations (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  descriptor VARCHAR(255),
  adults INT DEFAULT 0,
  child_0_1 INT DEFAULT 0,
  child_2_5 INT DEFAULT 0,
  child_6_9 INT DEFAULT 0,
  child_10_18 INT DEFAULT 0
);
```

Where each of those columns represents a particular amount. One thing I prefer to do when parsing arbitrary, often broken data is to preserve the exact input string in the table so you can check for mistakes. That's the purpose of the `descriptor` field here.

You could also create a proper one-to-many structure roughly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE accommodations (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  descriptor VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE accommodation_people (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  accommodation_id INT NOT NULL,
  age VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  number INT NOT NULL,
  KEY `index_on_accommodation_id` (accommodation_id)
);
```

In the `age` column you'd put something like `child(0-1)`, `0-1`, `19+` or whatever best represents that, so long as those values are consistent.

You'll have to judge if the overhead of having a derivative table provides any value here. I tend to try and steer towards a more normalized schema whenever possible, but in this case since the secondary table has only a handful of potential age values it's hard to say which is the best approach. If there was additional meta-data, like names and such, then the second model for "guests" would be the ideal.